# Trying to link products from a php session to an order(id)

Tags: php, mysql

Hello stackoverflowers,

I'm quite new to PHP, SQL and I am currently trying to create a self made ordering system. The system consists of a "shopping cart" of which contents I would like to link to an order. I have thought of the following 2 tables:

**ORDERS**

- order_id
- order_bag
- order_cash

**ORDER_PRODUCTS**

- order_product_id
- order_id
- order_quantity

Since 1 order can consist of multiple products, I tried to link them with 'order_id'. The problem now is that I do not have a clue how to this in my code. I have tried many queries, but I can't seem to link the two together. All the products in the shopping cart are stored in a php session.

query of inserting an order number:
INSERT INTO Orders (order_bag, order_cash) VALUES ('$bag','$cash')

Since order_id auto increments, I have not filled it in the statement, but each order will create a new order_id. How can I make sure that this order is used in my second statement, where I store all the products from my shopping cart in the ORDER_PRODUCTS table? I can't seem to use order_id right away, because it has not been filled in the ORDERS table yet.

query of inserting products:
INSERT INTO Orders_Products (order_id, order_quantity) VALUES ('$order_id','$product_qty')");

Any tips or other help is greatly appreciated.

Have a Nice Day!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Orders (order_bag, order_cash) VALUES ('$bag','$cash')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $order_id = $conn->insert_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to give you the basic idea. As far as I understand, you are trying to save order details along with product ids. First thing first, whenever you do insertion in multiple tables at once, always use [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html), so that if any error occurs after any query, it rollbacks the data.

Now, get the obviously you have the cart details, so keep that array and start the transaction and insert the order details (calculate total bill etc). Get the order id using LAST_INSERT_ID or `$connection->insert_id`. Now run the second set of your query. Generate one query to insert multiple rows in your `order_products` table. Insert in normal way and commit the transaction.

The first table will act as master table which consist the meta data of the order. Second table will use the `order_id` as foreign key and create a relationship between `order_id` and `product_id`. You don't need a AUTO INCREMENTED key for `order_products` table. Just make a composite key of `order_id` and `product_id`.